# How to store output of a function in a variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

How can I store a value from a function to a variable in bash which resets each time code is run. I tried something but it prints the value of the function after the code is ran

Answer (score 2):

Bash functions mimic the behaviour of processes but run in the same bash process by default. When functions are invoked with `$()` syntax they run in a sub-process.

You pass the arguments and capture the output of functions the same way as you do with processes:

```
function f() { echo "Hello, $1!"; }
f_output=$(f "world")
echo "f output is: $f_output"
```

Outputs:

```
f output is: Hello, world!
```

---

To understand `bash` and how it works you may like to read one good book about it.

Comment: Although this is perhaps a bit of an implementation detail, I do not think all bash functions run as a subprocess.  Supporting detail: If you delimit a bash function with { and }, you can change a variable in the function and it'll be changed in the caller.  If you delimit a bash function with ( and ), variables are local to the function.

Comment: @dstromberg You are quite right, `bash` function runs in the same process by default.

Comment: Functions don't run as subprocesses by default, but the contents of `$( )` does, so in this case it does run as a subprocess.